# Stored procedure with a query using union and temporary tables in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that uses temporary tables and union to query database:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE q_GetAllAttributesAndValuesByDocument(@IdDocument BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  
       AT.IDATRIBUTO,
       AT.NOMBREATRIBUTO,
       AD.VALORATRIBUTO
    INTO
       #TMP_ATTR
    FROM    
       ATRIBUTOS AT
    INNER JOIN 
       ATRIBUTOSXDOCUMENTO AD ON AT.IDATRIBUTO = AD.IDATRIBUTO
    WHERE 
       AD.IDDOCUMENTO2 = @IdDocument

    SELECT  
       TA.IDATRIBUTO AS Id,
       TA.NOMBREATRIBUTO AS Name,
       TA.VALORATRIBUTO AS Value
    FROM
       #TMP_ATTR TA

    UNION 

    SELECT  
       AT.IDATRIBUTO AS Id,
       AT.NOMBREATRIBUTO AS Name,
       '' AS Value
    FROM    
       ATRIBUTOS AT
    WHERE 
       IDATRIBUTO NOT IN (SELECT TA.IDATRIBUTO
                          FROM #TMP_ATTR TA)
END
```

When I add this stored procedure to my Entity Framework model, the complex type is not created, EF just return an integer from the stored procedure.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: What complex type are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CTE instead of temporary table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE q_GetAllAttributesAndValuesByDocument(@IdDocument BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH TMP_ATTR (Id, Name, Value)
    AS
    (
        SELECT  
           AT.IDATRIBUTO,
           AT.NOMBREATRIBUTO,
           AD.VALORATRIBUTO
        FROM    
           ATRIBUTOS AT
        INNER JOIN 
           ATRIBUTOSXDOCUMENTO AD ON AT.IDATRIBUTO = AD.IDATRIBUTO
        WHERE 
           AD.IDDOCUMENTO2 = @IdDocument
    )

    SELECT  
       TA.IDATRIBUTO AS Id,
       TA.NOMBREATRIBUTO AS Name,
       TA.VALORATRIBUTO AS Value
    FROM
       TMP_ATTR TA

    UNION 

    SELECT  
       AT.IDATRIBUTO AS Id,
       AT.NOMBREATRIBUTO AS Name,
       '' AS Value
    FROM    
       ATRIBUTOS AT
    WHERE 
       IDATRIBUTO NOT IN (SELECT TA.IDATRIBUTO
                          FROM TMP_ATTR TA)
```

Then update model from database.